# Setup symfony CMF

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-cmf

I want to start with Symfony CMF, but I have a problem. I followed [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/book/installation.html) but instead of using default SQL, I need MySQL with doctrine ORM, so I tried configuring it following [these](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/cookbook/installing_configuring_doctrine_phpcr_odm.html) [guides](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm.html). Everything looks good until I try to initiate database, by using following command using Doctrine ORM:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

but after firing

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

I get error: "No Metadata Classes to process."

As far as my conclusion goes, I need to create some classes which will act as routes, though nothing of that sort is mentioned in above guides. To avoid long post I setup git repo with [source code](https://github.com/sepikas-antanas/symfonycmf). What may be the cause of this problem, and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From your repository, it seems you did not configure doctrine orm at all. you are referencing the setup guides for phpcr-odm and your sandbox is configured to use phpcr-odm. you can [use jackalope-doctrine-dbal to use phpcr-odm with mysql](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm.html#phpcr-session-with-jackalope-doctrine-dbal).

if you really want to use the cmf with doctrine orm, only the RoutingBundle provides entities out of the box, and you will need to adjust those to suit your project.

Comment: I'm sorry for, probobly silly questions, but im really new to symfony and symfony cmf, and concepts like PHPCR. Yet still I realy wan't to start a project with. So where can I find more information or example how to configure cmf with doctrine orm?

Comment: there is not much info available on using the cmf with the orm. the only bit that comes with orm support out of the box is the RoutingBundle - have a look at that bundle to see how its done.

Comment: that said, i recommend you to look into phpcr-odm, its much better suited for content management and makes your live easier.